# Fixing the order of x labels in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the following graph, now I want to have a fixed order of the labels going from smaller to bigger, however pandas rearanges them to get a nice looking graph. I want it fixed so that it is easier to compare many graphs side by side.

[image]

This is the code im using:

```
def faultDistributionPlotSaveToDisk(key):
    sample_cut = pd.cut(freq_sample[key], bins=[1,10,100, 1000 ,100000], labels=["(1-10]", "(10-100]", "(100-1000]", "(1000-max]"])
    plot = sample_cut.value_counts(normalize=True).plot()
    fig = plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(key + ".png")
```

Comment: You need to show the code you're using to get that graph.

Comment: Sorry, abit stressed, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `sort=False` to [`value_counts()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts):

`plot = sample_cut.value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False).plot()`

This disables the descending sort by value.